# How to calculate max value for certain vector of column names and assign value to new column?

Tags: r, vector, data.table, max

After import my **dataset** looks as follows:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  820600 obs. of  2180 variables:
 $ count_comments                          : int  0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 1 ...
 $ count_faves                             : int  5 2 2 15 1 3 19 5 1 4 ...
 $ dateadded                               : int  1530174689 1530174688 1530174687 1530162494 1530159458 1530158648 1530158074 1529994404 1529992211 1529868922 ...
 $ datetaken                               : chr  "2018-05-10 15:50:59" "2018-05-10 15:50:53" "2018-05-10 15:50:03" "2006-11-27 00:00:00" ...
 $ dateupload                              : int  1530174672 1530174671 1530174669 1498275521 1436228321 1482723483 1496706006 1529994381 1529992197 1529868901 ...
 $ group_url                               : chr  "https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/" "https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/" "https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/" "https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/" ...
 $ id                                      :integer64 42341316794 42341318944 42341324184 35456820766 19292939750 31070311463 34738418140 42964602432 ... 
 $ license                                 : int  6 6 6 0 0 0 0 6 0 6 ...
 $ oid.800metres                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Abbey                               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Abdomen                             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Academicconference                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Academicdress                       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Accipitriformes                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Acousticguitar                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Acoustic-electricguitar             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Acrylicpaint                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Actionfigure                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Adolescent                          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Adult                               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Adventure                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Advertising                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aeolianlandform                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aerialphotography                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aerobatics                          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aerospaceengineering                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Africanelephant                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Afterglow                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Agaric                              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Agaricaceae                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Agaricus                            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Agriculturalmachinery               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Agriculture                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airforce                            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airracing                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airshow                             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airsports                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airtravel                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airbusa320family                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aircraft                            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aircraftcabin                       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aircraftcarrier                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aircraftengine                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airline                             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airliner                            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airplane                            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airport                             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airportapron                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Airportterminal                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aisle                               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Albumcover                          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Alcohol                             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Alcoholicbeverage                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Ale                                 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Algae                               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Alley                               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Alligator                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Alloywheel                          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.All-terrainvehicle                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Alps                                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Altar                               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Amateurboxing                       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Amateurwrestling                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Ambulance                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Americanfootball                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Amphibian                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Amphibiousassaultship               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Amphibioustransportdock             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Amphitheatre                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Amusementpark                       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Amusementride                       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Ancientgreektemple                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Ancienthistory                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Ancientromanarchitecture            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Ancientrome                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Animal                              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Animalmigration                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Animalshelter                       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Animalsports                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Animaltraining                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Anime                               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Annualplant                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Ant                                 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Antelope                            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Antique                             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Antiquecar                          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Apartment                           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Ape                                 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Apple                               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aqua                                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aquarium                            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aquaticplant                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Aqueduct                            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Arabiancamel                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Arcade                              : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Arch                                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Archbridge                          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Archaeologicalsite                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ oid.Archipelago                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

After that I import a **second data set** with the following structure:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2333 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Labels        : chr  "oid.800 metres" "oid.Abbey" "oid.Abdomen" "oid.Academic conference" ...
 $ CodingCategory: chr  "Unclear" "UrbanContext" "HumanBodyParts" "Unclear" ...
 $ Occurrences   : num  28 286 666 5925 569 ...
 $ Occurrences % : num  0.00341 0.03485 0.08116 0.72203 0.06934 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>
```

As you can see every "oid.XXX" Labels is assigned to one of the 12 CodingCategories:
- UrbanContext
- HumanBodyParts
- Animals
- SportsContext
- NatureContex
...

Here is a **snippet** of the **first datatset**:

```
    count_comments count_faves  dateadded           datetaken dateupload                                     group_url          id license oid.800metres
 1:              0           5 1530174689 2018-05-10 15:50:59 1530174672 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 42341316794       6             0
 2:              0           2 1530174688 2018-05-10 15:50:53 1530174671 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 42341318944       6             0
 3:              0           2 1530174687 2018-05-10 15:50:03 1530174669 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 42341324184       6             0
 4:              0          15 1530162494 2006-11-27 00:00:00 1498275521 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 35456820766       0             0
 5:              0           1 1530159458 2007-05-17 12:38:02 1436228321 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 19292939750       0             0
 6:              2           3 1530158648 2013-09-26 18:02:39 1482723483 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 31070311463       0             0
 7:              2          19 1530158074 2017-05-13 10:15:45 1496706006 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 34738418140       0             0
 8:              0           5 1529994404 2018-05-10 15:09:55 1529994381 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 42964602432       6             0
 9:              0           1 1529992211 2017-06-26 02:25:33 1529992197 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 28146093407       0             0
10:              1           4 1529868922 2018-05-10 13:42:01 1529868901 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 42984216801       6             0
    oid.Abbey oid.Abdomen oid.Academicconference oid.Academicdress oid.Accipitriformes oid.Acousticguitar oid.Acoustic-electricguitar oid.Acrylicpaint
 1:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
 2:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
 3:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
 4:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
 5:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
 6:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
 7:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
 8:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
 9:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
10:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
    oid.Actionfigure oid.Adolescent oid.Adult
 1:                0              0         0
 2:                0              0         0
 3:                0              0         0
 4:                0              0         0
 5:                0              0         0
 6:                0              0         0
 7:                0              0         0
 8:                0              0         0
 9:                0              0         0
10:                0              0         0
```

Here is a **snippet** of the **second data set**:

```
                          Labels CodingCategory Occurrences Occurrences %
 1:               oid.800 metres        Unclear          28   0.003412137
 2:                    oid.Abbey   UrbanContext         286   0.034852547
 3:                  oid.Abdomen HumanBodyParts         666   0.081160127
 4:      oid.Academic conference        Unclear        5925   0.722032659
 5:           oid.Academic dress           <NA>         569   0.069339508
 6:       oid.Academicconference        Unclear          NA            NA
 7:            oid.Academicdress           <NA>          NA            NA
 8:          oid.Accipitriformes        Animals          19   0.002315379
 9:          oid.Acoustic guitar           <NA>         329   0.040092615
10: oid.Acoustic-electric guitar           <NA>          43   0.005240068
11:            oid.Acrylic paint           <NA>         735   0.089568608
12:             oid.Acrylicpaint        Unclear          NA            NA
13:            oid.Action figure           <NA>        3650   0.444796490
14:             oid.Actionfigure           <NA>          NA            NA
15:               oid.Adolescent HumanBodyParts        1123   0.136851085
16:                    oid.Adult HumanBodyParts         983   0.119790397
17:                oid.Adventure           <NA>       17603   2.145137704
18:              oid.Advertising           <NA>       46194   5.629295637
19:         oid.Aeolian landform  NatureContext        5911   0.720326590
20:          oid.Aeolianlandform  NatureContext          NA            NA
21:       oid.Aerial photography        Unclear       10382   1.265171825
22:        oid.Aerialphotography        Unclear          NA            NA
23:               oid.Aerobatics  SportsContext         224   0.027297100
24:    oid.Aerospace engineering           <NA>        1526   0.185961492
25:     oid.Aerospaceengineering           <NA>          NA            NA
26:         oid.African elephant        Animals           7   0.000853034
27:                oid.Afterglow  NatureContext        1998   0.243480380
28:                   oid.Agaric  NatureContext           1   0.000121862
29:              oid.Agaricaceae  NatureContext           1   0.000121862
30:                 oid.Agaricus  NatureContext           1   0.000121862
31:   oid.Agricultural machinery        CarType       34249   4.173653424
32:              oid.Agriculture           <NA>       12034   1.466487936
33:                oid.Air force           <NA>        8143   0.992322691
34:               oid.Air racing  SportsContext          79   0.009627102
35:                 oid.Air show  SportsContext         331   0.040336339
36:               oid.Air sports  SportsContext         113   0.013770412
37:               oid.Air travel           <NA>         551   0.067145991
38:       oid.Airbus a320 family           <NA>          73   0.008895930
39:                 oid.Aircraft           <NA>       20583   2.508286620
40:           oid.Aircraft cabin           <NA>           3   0.000365586
41:         oid.Aircraft carrier           <NA>           5   0.000609310
42:          oid.Aircraft engine           <NA>       59190   7.213014867
43:                  oid.Airline           <NA>        8080   0.984645381
44:                 oid.Airliner           <NA>        1343   0.163660736
45:                 oid.Airplane           <NA>       12043   1.467584694
46:                  oid.Airport   UrbanContext        2386   0.290762856
47:            oid.Airport apron           <NA>         133   0.016207653
48:         oid.Airport terminal   UrbanContext         714   0.087009505
49:          oid.Airportterminal   UrbanContext          NA            NA
50:                oid.Airtravel           <NA>          NA            NA
```

What I am trying to do now is create additional columns in the 1st data set that gives me the Max Value of the "oid.XXX" values for all the "oid.XXX" colums that match a specific CodingCategory per row. For example: I want to create a new column named "UrbanContext" that contains the Max Value for its corresponding "Oid.XXX" values in the specific row. This is what I came up with so far:

```
require(data.table)
require(QuantPsyc)
library(lmSupport)
library(dbplyr)

#Import header of OID Label Data only
x <- fread("/Users/01_Flickr Car Data/01_Open Image Data Set/01_Raw Data/flickrexport_cars_oid_201903.csv",sep=",", encoding = "Latin-1", header=TRUE, nrows=0)

#Define oid Columns as numeric
colNames <- grep('^oid', names(x), value = TRUE)
colClasses <- rep('numeric', length(colNames))
names(colClasses) <- colNames 

#Import OID Label Data based on Open Image Data Set only
flickrcar <- fread("/Users/01_Flickr Car Data/01_Open Image Data Set/01_Raw Data/flickrexport_cars_oid_201903.csv",colClasses = colClasses, sep=",", encoding = "Latin-1", header=TRUE)
str(flickrcar)

#NAs to zeros
f_dowle3 = function(DT) {
  for (j in names(DT))
    set(DT,which(is.na(DT[[j]])),j,0)
}
f_dowle3(flickrcar)

#Import Coding for Open Image Data Set Labels
flickrcar_label_coding <- fread("/Users/01_Open Image Data Set/01_Raw Data/180220_OID_Labels_Coding_NTT_FINAL.csv", sep=",", header = TRUE)

flickrcar_label_coding[1:50, 1:4]

#Set to Data Table
setDT(flickrcar)
setDT(flickrcar_label_coding)

#Group OID Labels into LabelCategory
humanbodyparts <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("HumanBodyParts",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
urbancontext <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("UrbanContext",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
animals <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("Animals",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
sportscontext <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("SportsContext",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
naturecontext <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("NaturContext",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
exhibitioncontext <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("ExhibitionContext",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
manualimageprocessing <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("ManualImageProcessing",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
regularroadecomtext <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("RegularRoadContext",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
racingcontext <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("RacingContext",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
cartype <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("CarType",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
carparts <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("CarParts",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]
carbrand <- flickrcar_label_coding[grep("CarBrand",flickrcar_label_coding$CodingCategory), "Labels"]

#Insert Label Category Columns
flickrcar$HumanBodyParts <- flickrcar[1, which.max(flickrcar[1,humanbodyparts])]
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

In the end the result for one row should look something like this:

```
count_comments count_faves  dateadded           datetaken dateupload                                     group_url          id license oid.800metres
1:              0           5 1530174689 2018-05-10 15:50:59 1530174672 https://www.flickr.com/groups/capriceclassic/ 42341316794       6             0
   oid.Abbey oid.Abdomen oid.Academicconference oid.Academicdress oid.Accipitriformes oid.Acousticguitar oid.Acoustic-electricguitar oid.Acrylicpaint
1:         0           0                      0                 0                   0                  0                           0                0
   oid.Actionfigure oid.Adolescent oid.Adult NatureContext RoadContext... 
1:                0              0         0          0.88        0.54...
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: could you add a small `dput()` reproducible sample and expected result? its not clear to me where you extract the max value from.

Comment: @boski thanks for your response, i just updated the data above. I hope my problem is clearer now